# How to deal with match in a Coq proof

Tags: coq

I'm wondering what are strategies to deal with matches in proof. For example, I have something in the following form:

```
F match something m' with
  | true => Y m'
  | false => Z m'
  end=Otherside m'
```

It feels like there should be a number of ways to deal with this...I imagine that it might be possible to refactor things upstream to avoid, but it also feels like the following should be true

```
match something m' with
| true => F (Y m')
| false => F (Z m')
end=Otherside m'
```

And then you should be able to to do something like break this into two subgoals, where if

```
F (Y m')=Otherside m'
F (Z m')=Otherside m'
```

Then you are good to go.

Is this possible? Or do I need to refactor my functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't go through your intermediate step, but you get to your two goals simply by

```
destruct (something m').
```

If that term is too big to write, I suppose you can pull it out like so:

```
match goal with |- _ match ?S with _ => _ end = _ => destruct S end.
```

or even

```
match goal with |- context[match ?S with _ => _ end] => destruct S end.
```